# SQL and Google Charts - Given a series of dates, scale date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts to create some graphs and it's working well. The only problem I'm having is when I have a large date range. My X axis displays the series of dates. It's fine for 1 and 2 weeks (only weekdays, so I either have 5 or 10 dates) however when I start to get up into the month(s) range, all the dates overlap one another and it's unreadable. Ideally, for anything over 2 weeks, I'd like to get the 10 most significant dates. So for example, if my series is all the dates from 6/1 - 7/15, I'd like the X axis on the graph to display something like:

6/1 | 6/5 | 6/10 | 6/15 | 6/20 | 6/25 | 6/30 | 7/5 | 7/10 | 7/15

With Google Charts, you have to specify your series of data, so I can't just provide a start and end date and have it scale appropriately. FYI - I'm using a SQL Server stored proc to obtain my data so I'd like to be able to calculate the dates on the database side.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understand your requirement and here is a piece of code which will form a String separated by ";" which you can return from the SQL Server SP!

```
begin
    declare @dt1 as smalldatetime
    declare @dt2 as smalldatetime
    declare @intDays as int
    declare @curDt as smalldatetime
    declare @interV as int
    declare @outText as varchar(1000)

    set @dt1 = '6/1/2011'
    set @dt2 = '7/15/2011'
    set @interv = 10

    set @intdays = datediff(dd,@dt1,@dt2) / @interv
    set @curDt = @dt1
    set @outText = ''
    while (@curdt < @dt2)
    begin
        set @outText = @outText + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @curdt, 1) + ';'
        set @curdt = dateadd(dd, @interv, @curdt)
    end
    if @curdt >= @dt2
        set @outText = @outText + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @dt2, 1) + ';'

    set @outText = substring(@outText, 1, len(@outText)-1)

    print @outtext
end
```

@dt1 and @dt2 are the start and end dates, which you can replace with your local variables. @outText is the string with values.

Let me know if you have any questions or you want this as a function/procedure!